# Detect continuous touch position in view with UIScrollView still active

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I am interested in getting the touch location (e.g. something that is, or mimics `touchesMoved`) in a view controller's view while still keeping a `UIScrollView` subview enabled. Since all of the `touchesDidSomething` methods are consumed by the `UIScrollView`, my hope is that there's a roundabout way of achieving this.

Here are a few things I've tried:

- Subclassing a `UIScrollView`, overriding it's `touchesMoved` method and passing that touch information to a `custom delegate` method in my `scrollView's` view controller. --> This actually works if I deselect "cancellable content touches" and "delays content touches" on my scroll `view` but it prevents my scroll `view` from scrolling.
- Using the same tactic as above but with a subclassed `UIView` as a sibling to my `UIScrollView`. Hence, the hierarchy is as follows:

`view
   UIScrollView
      Subview
      Subview
   CustomUIView` <-- custom `UIView` that calls `delegate`

Both of these methods work to the extent that I can grab the data, but at the expense of my scroll view not scrolling anymore. I know I can grab the location of a touch event in a `UIScrollView` similar to a `touchesBegan` while the `scrollView` continues to work but I haven't found a way to get continuous touch events while scrolling. Is this possible?

Here's an illustration of what I'm after:

[image]

For some metadata as to why I'm looking for this and why grabbing something like `scrollViewDidScroll`'s `contentOffset.x` won't work, I'm specifically interested in when the `scrollView` has scrolled to the end (or beginning) and a user is attempting to keep swiping forward (or backward) even though the `scrollView` can't scroll in the swiped direction anymore. When this happens I want to detect the forward (or backward) swipe motion to initiate a slick transition to another view.

Comment: How about detecting touch on the ParentView, and converting the location of the touch with the subview added in UIScrollview? For reference check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW52)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a panning gesture recognizer to my view and using it's `translationInView` method (`UISwipeGestureRecognizer` doesn't have this method). Example below

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(myMethod(_:)))
panGesture.delegate = self
self.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

func myMethod(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // sender.translationInView(self).x
}
```

Also making sure to return true for `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` in the `UIGestureRegognizerDelegate` to account for the scrollView.